# Japanese text in 'Related' box rendering strangely

Tags: bug, status-completed, furigana, design

While looking at [a recent question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33725/i-know-all-hiragana-and-30-katakana-but-i-cant-read-japanese), I noticed the 'Related' box on the right side looked rather odd:

> [image]

The actual questions seem fine:

- [When grandmas tell their kids お天道様がみてるよ, how do the kids know who お天道様 is?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/when-grandmas-tell-their-kids-%E3%81%8A%E5%A4%A9%E9%81%93%E6%A7%98%E3%81%8C%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88-how-do-the-kids-know-who-%E3%81%8A%E5%A4%A9%E9%81%93%E6%A7%98-is?rq=1)
- [Non-Japanese can know their "マナー", but not their "礼儀{れいぎ}"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18126/non-japanese-can-know-their-%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC-but-not-their-%E7%A4%BC%E5%84%80%E3%82%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%8E?rq=1)

So I think it's just the 'Related' box at the right.

Any idea what's wrong?  It seems to be related to the furigana script; the problem goes away if I disable JavaScript. It happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I was initially mystified why SE did this, but I think they might've done it to allow more content to be displayed on sites that use MathJax, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564768/zetaem-to-er-otimes-r-m-is-a-group-isomorphism?rq=1 (although even there it renders strangely for me on FF/Ubuntu) - I could hack around this in the Furigana engine, but I think it'd be cleaner if this was fixed in the CSS of this site itself.

Comment: Related issue on Mathematics.se meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23073/mathjax-broken-in-related-section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS has been updated by SE, so the Furigana/Japanese font elements should be rendering properly now.

Further details are at [Titles with MathJax break in the related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278752/titles-with-mathjax-break-in-the-related-questions).

Answer (score 2):

I was waiting for someone to post something about this :)

It seems to be due to `.spacer > a.question-hyperlink` being styled with `display: flex` - if you replace that style with `display: inline`, the problem goes away.

The solutions appear to be:

1. Remove `flex` from that element, and change it back to `inline` (I think that's what those hyperlinks were previously set to?)
2. Disable Japanese font override `span` tags <sub>(i.e. the `<span lang="ja">` tags inside the hyperlinks, which are added by the Furigana engine to make sure Japanese uses the right fonts).</sub>
3. Make the entire hyperlink render in a Japanese font, not just Japanese text, and don't add `<span lang="ja">` tags.

Any of these three should solve this problem, *but* the second two would still have issues if titles with Furigana are in the hyperlinks, which would mean I would need to disable/put in brackets Furigana in hyperlinks if I did this.

As a result, the first option looks the most attractive to me.

Comment: Some titles do seem to render properly, but only if all of their Japanese characters are connected to ASCII characters without spaces.

Comment: @Sjiveru I don't know the full mechanics of `display: flex`, I only heard of this property yesterday, but I don't think that's true from my testing. `flex` renders differently for me when there's no more room on a line (example screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dcTcc.png).  It also looks like whitespace in-between element nodes/text nodes is ignored, similar to the way it often is for `block`-styled elements, which might be what you're seeing.